# iOS Swift, cell in UITableView not taking whole width

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My project currently has a view, which is a UIViewController, in that view controller I have a UIViewTable that shows a list of devices that I can tap on to open a settings menu for each device. The list shows up correctly and the tapping actions are also working fine.

My problem is that the display cuts off the cells a little to the left and right. The separators also had a margin to the left but I could fix it in my storyboard by changing the separator inset to custom and = 0.

The overwhelming response to that problem is to add :

```
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Under

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

But this had no effect for me. Here's the picture of my display, any help would be really appreciated!

[image: display]

Note: If that helps, when I tap the cell, the highlight does cover the whole width which seems a little odd to me, but I'm not sure what to do with that information.

Comment: it might be possible you may have given background color to label just a guess.You can check your storyboard design once.

Comment: The cell is not the problem. It's something about its contents. You have a wonderful debugger. Debug! Use the View Debugger to reveal what the black inset thing _is_.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the answer, I'm very new to iOS this is the first app I've worked on so I didn't know there was a way to debug the UI easily. I'll have to look into that!

Comment: @TusharSharma Thank you this was indeed the problem, I was setting the label background colour rather than the actual background.

Comment: @lhbortho np mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the whitespace only appears to the right and the left of your cels, it's clearly part of the cels themselves. Check the Background color of the cell view - it's probably set to white.

Comment: This did fix the problem. I was setting the labels background color rather than the actual background color. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear I was of help.

Comment: @lhbortho confused...what was the solution? What were doing wrong? I mean if it's just as jglasse said then shouldn't the entire cell have a white background?

Comment: Not if the label background is set to black.

Comment: @Honey Yep, like jglasse said, I was changing label background and since the label doesn't cover the entire cell it resulted in the picture I posted.